# Automatic migration between different Persistent backends

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

I wonder if there's a tool for automatic migrations between different DBMS's using the Persistent package. In theory, it should be relatively easy to do, so I thought there should be a tool already written to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (maybe hacky) solution is to just create a program that uses `mkPersist` twice in different modules with the same definitions but different backend configurations, and to then manually perform the copy operation.

There is, however, not a tool currently available to do this as far as I know.